# stat() function not returning correctly

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, stat

I have this function

```
long processFile(char * fileName)
{
    struct stat statBuf;
    mode_t mode;
    int result;
    result = stat(fileName, &statBuf);
    if (result == -1);
        return -1;
    if(S_ISDIR(mode))
        return(processDirectory(fileName));
    else
        return 1;
}
```

If the "fileName" is an actual file I want it to return one, but if "fileName" is a directory I want it to go to my function called `processDirectory`.  For some reason no matter what I do, the `stat()` call keeps returning a `-1`.  I have tried hard coding a file name like "test.txt" and a directory called "/test" which both live in the same directory as my executable.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: The value of `errno` is?

Comment: errno? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Yes. Just like it says in the **RETURN VALUE** section of the `stat(2)` man page.

Comment: replace `return -1;` with `{ perror("stat"); return -1; };`

Comment: ... or (more educative): `{fprintf(stderr, "stat() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); return -1;}`  @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: I replaced `result = stat(fileName, &statBuf); if (result == -1);return -1;` with `if(stat(fileName, &statBuf) == -1){ perror("stat() error "); return -1; }` and now it is working.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Wow, what a lot of blindness here ... see my answer.

Comment: " now it is working" -- because you removed the bogus `;` after the if statement, not because of perror call.

Comment: BTW, you're in "good" company with this error -- google "goto fail".

Comment: "replace return -1; with { perror("stat"); return -1; };" -- actually, that exact replacement would still always return -1, and also add yet another bogus `;`.

Comment: "The compiler is wrong," "the operating system is returning wrong results" are, in my *extensive experience*, right one time in a million or so.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, as soon as I saw that title I knew its author was a neophyte. We get a lot of that here. With experience comes humility, at least in this area -- the mistakes are almost always our own,  we're capable of a vast range of them, and are often completely blind to them. (In this case I saw the semicolon within a fraction of a second of looking at the code, but I've spent 40 years at it.)

Comment: @JimBalter First, I just want to say thanks for finding my typo. Also, how would you suggest I word the title to show humility to such an experienced person?

Comment: The first thing to do is to verify the claim by running a debugger or putting in a printf of the value stat actually returns. As for the title, "stat isn't returning expected value" would avoid the implication that it is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (result == -1);
    return -1;
```

Remove the semicolon from the first line.

Comment: Yeah, same goes for Apple: http://www.zdnet.com/apples-goto-fail-needs-a-massive-culture-change-to-fix-7000026783/

Answer (score 1):

From Your Post it looks like there could be some problem with the user security or the way directory may not have appropriate authorization for searching. Anyway you can do the quick testing by using 'stat' command and check whether its working or not.

$ stat filename.txt

Yes errno at the time of stat() returning -1 would be helpful to understand why this system call is failing.

Comment: Aside from this not getting at the right issue (see my answer), it's not an answer at all, it's a comment. Please post comments as comments (you now have enough rep to do so), not as answers.